# Post as someone else

Tags: users

I'm starting a blog where multiple people will be "posting". However, most of my authors don't want to have anything to do with the posting process of WP. So they will be sending the articles to someone who would basically do a copy paste and post it, but it has to be as if the author itself did it.

Currently we have to log in as each author and post the content for them. So I would like to know if there's a way to do it from a single account and select a "post as" option and select who you want to post as from a dropdown.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you get them to register as a contributor and submit a draft post. You can then change the author to anyone else of needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're logged into WordPress as an administrator, you can easily change the post author of a post to someone else.

So what you'll want to do is set up different user accounts for your different authors and then set yourself up as an administrator. Then when you go to publish a post using your administrator account you can select which author you want it to be published under.

This video is old, but it more or less outlines the process of what you're looking to do: http://wpu.me/change-post-author/